# Как мне вызвать подфункцию из основного тела программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть модуль, в нем есть функция big, а в ней - куча мелких. В общем теле модуля есть функция load, которая должна по полученной строке(строка уже известна, тут помощь не нужна) вызывать одну из функций из big, у которой имя совпадает со строкой. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
def big():
    def a1():
       ...
    def a2():
       ...

def load(str_func_name):
    что тут писать?
```

Comment: Вам именно такое поведение нужно? Если что, функция это объект и ее можно вызывать в функции. И если честно, то не понятно как функция сможет вызывать что-то не из своей области памяти...

Comment: Т.е. грубо говоря, лоад не видит ничего, что находится в биг.

Comment: Если у вас `big` просто контейнер для других функций (а сама функция `big` ничего не делает), то просто сделайте big классом, а `a1` и `a2` статическими методами (добавьте декоратор `@staticmethod` перед ними), потом вызывайте функции как `big.a1()`, `big.a2()`.

Comment: Я уже решил проблему, перенеся код из модуля в основной файл. big лишь вызывала a1, а так она нужна была только для того, чтобы все переменные из основного модуля один раз в одно место скинуть в модуль

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
def big():
    global d_funcs = {'a1' : a1, 'a2' : a2}
...

def load(str_func_name):
    f = d_funcs(str_func_name)
...
```

Comment: Понятно, что global d_funcs должен быть ПОСЛЕ функций, а не перед.